# Unsure if im calling element children correctly here

Tags: javascript

Heres what I currently have for my code:

```
var divArray = ["test", "love"]
var delayArray = ["delaya", "delayb", "delayc", "delayd", "delaye", "delayf", "delayg", "delayh", "delayi", "delayj", "delayk", "delayl", "delaym", "delaya", "delayb", "delayc", "delayd", "delaye", "delayf", "delayg", "delayh", "delayi", "delayj", "delayk", "delayl", "delaym"];

function zip(a, b, f) {
    for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++){
        f(a[i], b[i]);
    };
}

function phase(){
            var divGroup = this.children();
    for(var i=0; i < divGroup.length; i++){
        this.children()[i].className = 'wave ' + delayArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)];
    }
}


for(var i = 0; i < divArray.length; i++) { 
    document.getElementById(divArray[i]).addEventListener('animationend', phase, false);
}

zip(divArray, delayArray, function(x, y) { 
    document.getElementById(x).className = 'transtart burn ' + y;
});
```

And heres a jsfiddle of what Im trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/ACLM6/1/

Pretty much I want the two new classes to be added to the element children of the element that the `animationend` triggered on. But Im not sure if Im calling the element children correctly in `phase()`.

Comment: @Jack Its a global variable that I didnt list here. My original question was if I was calling the children of the element correctly. Sorry I forgot to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should call it: `$(this).children()` - jQuery method,

or `this.children` - DOM node property.

Comment: Youre awesome, now if I can only figure out why the animation is not playing the second time and the divs are just going back to 0 opacity when the eventListener fires.